# edit multiple rows using same button using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to edit multiple rows using one button using jquery. Since I've used row span so when I click on edit button,only the value of single row is editable. Here is the code snippet

```js
$('.editbtn3').click(function() {
  var edit = $(this).text().trim() == 'Edit';
  $(this).html($(this).text().trim() == 'Edit' ? 'Save' : 'Edit');
  $(this).parents('tbody').find($("tr.set"+$(this).data("set")+">td").not(":nth-child(1),:last-child")).each(function() {
    if (edit) {
      $(this).prop('contenteditable', true).css({
        'background': '#fff',
        'color': '#000'
      })
    } else {
      $(this).prop('contenteditable', false).removeAttr("style");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-striped table-dark table-bordered" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">S.N</th>
      <th scope="col">abc</th>
      <th scope="col">def</th>
      <th scope="col">option</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="set1">
      <th scope="row" rowspan="2">1</th>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>21st August</td>
      <td rowspan="2" ><button type="button" data-set="1" class="btn btn-primary editbtn3">Edit</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="set1">
      <td>21</td>
      <td>21st August</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="set2">
      <th scope="row" rowspan="2">2</th>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>21st August</td>
      <td rowspan="2"><button type="button" data-set="2" class="btn btn-primary editbtn3">Edit</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="set2">
      <td>21</td>
      <td>21st August</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Here I am only able to edit single row. Do I have to use loop for multiple rows editing or is there another solution?

Comment: You want to edit one row at a time or multiple rows using one button ?

Comment: `$(this).parents('tr')` will ONLY find the cells on the row with the button. I suggest you do not use tables but class.

Comment: @AmbrishPathak I want to edit multiple rows using single button

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry I didnot get what you are trying to say.Could you explain a little?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(this).parents('tr')` will ONLY find the cells on the row with the button.

If you have sets, I suggest using data-attr - I am testing for rowspan to eliminate the cells that should be left alone - you can use a class or other ways of selecting. Because of the rowspans you cannot use the :first-child and :last-child selectors.

```js
$('.editbtn3').click(function() {
  var edit = $(this).text().trim() == 'Edit';
  $(this).html($(this).text().trim() == 'Edit' ? 'Save' : 'Edit');
  var $rows = $("tr.set" + $(this).data("set"));
  $rows.each(function() {
    $(this).find("td").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("rowspan")) return false;
      if (edit) {
        $(this).prop('contenteditable', true).css({
          'background': '#fff',
          'color': '#000'
        })
      } else {
        $(this).prop('contenteditable', false).removeAttr("style");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-striped table-dark table-bordered" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">S.N</th>
      <th scope="col">abc</th>
      <th scope="col">def</th>
      <th scope="col">option</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="set1">
      <th scope="row" rowspan="2">1</th>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>20th August</td>
      <td rowspan="2"><button type="button" data-set="1" class="btn btn-primary editbtn3">Edit</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="set1">
      <td>21</td>
      <td>21st August</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="set2">
      <th scope="row" rowspan="2">2</th>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>22nd August</td>
      <td rowspan="2"><button type="button" data-set="2" class="btn btn-primary editbtn3">Edit</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="set2">
      <td>23</td>
      <td>23rd August</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Well it worked.Thanks a lot.But when i added another row having S.N 2 then on clicking the button edit,both the datas of S.N 1 and S.N 2 are editable which is not desirable.On clickin the edit button of S.N 1,only the datas of S.N1 shouldbe able to get edited,not of S.N2.

Comment: Well,instead of giving noedit class to the button and the sn, i tried to do using nth child selector (.not(":nth-child(1),:last-child"))) but it didnot work.Adding the class to all other elements seem unfeasible because if there were 30 fields,it will be time consuming to add noedit to every element which we wish to become uneditable.I'm updating the snippet by adding the nth-child selector.Hope you will take a look at it :)

Comment: If there are 30 fields, only the first and last has the noedit. but I will look

Comment: I've updated the code.Yes if we use the class noedit only the first and last won't be editable but if we have to edit odd or even or every 3rd among many fields while other being uneditable it will be time consuming using class.Hope you get what I am trying to say

Comment: You cannot use the first and last-child selectors because of the rowspans. I have instead used the rowspans as eliminators

Comment: If we want to edit those first and last how could we do that??

Comment: I do not understand. Do you want to edit them or not. First not, now you do. Remove the constraints or add the cells using [.add](https://api.jquery.com/add/)

Comment: Well I will try and let you know the results